# Model Animation using VTK

Tags: animation, 3d, vtk, 3d-modelling

I have a VTK data file for a 3D model and I am trying to show a transformation applied to it.

I have the point coordinates/polygon data for every state in the transformation (there should be about 10-30 states), i.e. I could write another VTK file for each step.

I am trying to create a nice animation where each state would be shown for say, 1 second and then switch to the next one, as fluently as possible.

What would be the best thing to do?

Answer (score 2):

There are a [handful of ways](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx#Animation) to animate something in VTK, with examples on the VTK Wiki.

The easiest way is probably to subclass `vtkCommand` ([DataAnimationSubclass](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/DataAnimationSubclass)), but the "VTK/right" way is with `vtkAnimationScene` ([AnimationScene](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/AnimationScene)).

Comment: `vtkAnimationScene` animate will stop `vtkRenderWindowInteractor` Loop when  it Play(). That is we can not interact with RenderWindow when `vtkAnimationScene` is playing.